# Select max time of datetime column group by other datetime column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to have a result of unique row of `id`, `date_col1`, with max (or last) of `date_col2`, and the `value` contained in the same row as `max(date_col2)`.

My table is like this sample:

| id | date_col1 | date_col2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-02 12:00:00 | 2023-01-02 12:00:00 | 10 |
| 1 | 2023-01-02 12:00:00 | 2023-01-02 13:00:00 | 3 |
| 1 | 2023-01-02 13:00:00 | 2023-01-02 12:00:00 | 5 |
| 1 | 2023-01-02 13:00:00 | 2023-01-02 13:00:00 | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-01-02 13:00:00 | 2023-01-02 14:00:00 | 7 |
| 1 | 2023-01-02 13:00:00 | 2023-01-02 15:00:00 | 4 |
| 2 | 2023-01-02 12:00:00 | 2023-01-02 12:00:00 | 5 |
| 2 | 2023-01-02 12:00:00 | 2023-01-02 13:00:00 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-01-02 13:00:00 | 2023-01-02 13:00:00 | 7 |
| 2 | 2023-01-02 13:00:00 | 2023-01-02 18:00:00 | 4 |

Desired result:

| id | date_col1 | date_col2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-02 12:00:00 | 2023-01-02 13:00:00 | 3 |
| 1 | 2023-01-02 13:00:00 | 2023-01-02 15:00:00 | 4 |
| 2 | 2023-01-02 12:00:00 | 2023-01-02 13:00:00 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-01-02 13:00:00 | 2023-01-02 18:00:00 | 4 |

Right now I can get that result with this query:

```
with max_date_col2 as (select id,date_col1,max(date_col2) as max_col1 from table
group by id,date_col1 order by date_col1)
select table.* from max_date_col2 max join table on max.id=table.id and max.date_col1=table.date_col1 and max.date_col2=table.date_col2;
```

But it seems inefficient. Is there some way with one `SELECT` query, without additional CTE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't look to MySQL solutions if you are running Postgres.
`DISTINCT ON` is **much** simpler:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id, date_col1)
       id, date_col1, date_col2, value
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY id, date_col1, date_col2 DESC;
```

See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: Thanks for modifying and answering the question. I am using PostgreSQL, and I replaced the query with your method. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

it was duplicated question:
[Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql)

got a hint from above and got it right using leftjoin and <.